# Ejb3Configuration.addPackage() does not find entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I want to add known JPA entities programatically when creating EntityManagerFactory.
So I have this sequence (Hibernate 3.6)

```
 Ejb3Configuration ejbConf = new Ejb3Configuration();
 ejbConf.configure("TestPU", null);
 ejbConf.addPackage("org.jboss.jawabot.irc.ent");
 ejbConf.addPackage("org.jboss.jawabot.irc.model");
 emf = ejbConf.buildEntityManagerFactory();
```

I also tried calling addPackage()'s before configure().
Adding packages is fine.
However, Hibernate does not find the entities. When I persist it, I get:

> Unknown entity: org.jboss.jawabot.irc.model.IrcMessage

What's wrong? How do I make Hbernate recognize entities from those packages?

Thanks,
Ondra

**Update:** The project is [here](http://ondrazizka.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/bots/JawaBot/branches/2.0/core/src/main/java/org/jboss/weld/environment/se/jpa/EntityManagerStoreImpl.java).
A bit messy because I am trying few tricks in that.

And note, entities from the "core" module (jar) of the app  are picked up.

Comment: Can you show the `IrcMessage` class? Does it have the `@Entity` annotation?

Comment: Also try using `addAnnotatedClass` and add the classes one by one to see if it fails as well or not?

Comment: Behrang, with `addAnnotatedClass()` it works. Weird. Which means Hibernate fails to scan the package. I will debug and tell.

Comment: I found this https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/EJB-252  but still I don't get it - what would adding a package be good for if not for loading it's entities...

Comment: Okay, seems it's only for the purpose of having Hibernate's annotations on packages (not sure which ones but I'll check that later :)

Comment: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6466  Improve javadoc of Ejb3Configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anwser is, the purpose of `addPackage()` is only to tell Hibernate to take given package's annotations into account, *not* to load it's Entities.

More, `Ejb3Configuration` will be deprecated for 4.0 in favor of `EntityManagerFactoryBuilder`, see https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6159 .

Comment: By the way, by default all your `@Entity` annotated classes will be discovered inside a JavaEE 5/6 container. Are you deploying your app outside a container or something?

Comment: Yes, I have a standalone app.